# sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats slow on first run after rebuilding indexes

Tags: sql-server, index, transaction, performance, performance-tuning

I have a 10GB database in SQL Server 2016 RC1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 where I just performed many insert and delete operations. Afterwards, I ran:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD"
```

Next I run:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID('db'), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED');
```

The first time I run this command, it finishes in 2:26 (mm:ss).
Subsequent executes finish in around 1:30.

I am not looking for a workaround. I need to know WHY this performance increase occurs because I have similar transactions that are operating the same way.

I have tried updating the statistics (using sp_updatestats) before running the SELECT query but it does not make much performance difference.

I have also tried to recreate the issue by clearing the SQL Server cache as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873025/how-can-i-clear-the-sql-server-query-cache and rebooting the machine. However, the query still executes in around 1:30 after this, so I do not believe this is a caching issue as suggested in similar posts.

I can only repeat the problem by doing all the inserts, deletes, and index rebuilding mentioned previously.

Extra information:

- I am using the default fillfactor of 100 for all tables.
- sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats shows 132804 wait_time_ms for
  PAGEIOLATCH_SH after the first execution and 85,635 after the second
  execution.
- sys.dm_os_latch_stats shows 147313 wait_time_ms for BUFFER
  after the first execution with 54137 waiting_requests_count and 2344 max_wait_time
- MAX DOP is 0 for database
- 8 GB RAM on Server
- 4 Core CPU (2.3 GHz) on Server

Is there something missing after the index rebuilding that is causing this issue? What other steps can I take to isolate the problem?

Comment: You're rebuilding all indexes on all tables and you're worried about why the first time you check physical stats after that it takes 40 seconds longer?

Comment: Have you considered that the subsequent runs were aided by pages in the buffer pool?

Comment: When following the instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873025/how-can-i-clear-the-sql-server-query-cache, I ran CHECKPOINT; GO DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; GO DBCC FREEPROCCACHE; GO. Wouldn't this clear the pages in the buffer pool?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: If instead of running dm_db_index_physical_stats, I log into my web application and perform a transaction that involves inserts on some of the larger tables, the first transaction takes 40 seconds longer than the second one. No user should have to experience that. I am trying to find out why this occurs so I can find the best strategy to take when I rebuild indexes as part of an upgrade/migration strategy for my software.

Comment: Ok, so rephrase your question to actually explain your *real* problem. Maybe include the query that takes 40+ seconds, the actual post-execution plan, etc. In any case, after a rebuild, yes, you will need to wait for the pages to be loaded into the buffer pool again. So perhaps you can add something to your maintenance procedure like a SELECT * FROM table (adding index hints if you want specific indexes to be pre-loaded). Of course this only works if you don't have other, bigger tables vying more aggressively for physical memory...

Comment: I do not know which query to post because I have this performance problem with any transaction that is run first in my application. This problem occurs after using SqlBulkCopy to transport a database from Oracle to SQL Server. Then I rebuild all the indexes in SQL Server. My question is if this were a buffer pool problem, why would dm_db_index_physical_stats not run at the slower time (2:26) after clearing the buffer cache as mentioned above?